# Replacement of switch statement - getting properties via a string name

Tags: c#, wpf, switch-statement

Basically, i have a system in place where my datagrid marks cells that have changed with a new background colour, to do this i have a method in the object that contains these properties that receives a string which is the name of the property to check, and then a switch statement that takes that string to check the correct property.

```
public Color HasChanged(string value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case "CILRef":
            if (_localShipment.cilRef != _originalShipment.cilRef)
            {
                return Colors.SkyBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                return Colors.White;
            }
        case "ArrivedAtPortDate":
            if (_localShipment.arrivedAtPortDate != _originalShipment.arrivedAtPortDate)
            {
                return Colors.SkyBlue;
            }
            else
            {
                return Colors.White;
            }
    }
}
```

I've removed the rest of the properties for brevity.

Now i get the nagging sensation that there is a cleaner way to do this string>property without using a switch statement, but i can't for the life of me find anything on google, it's hard to search without some keyword to go on.

I'm also attempting to only save those properties that have changed, i was going to place any changed property name into an array, and then have a loop with yet another switch statement that checked that array and then saved the correct property. However this again seems untidy to me.

is there a cleaner solution to this, hopefully that could handle the addition of new properties without needing to add new code to the switch statements.

I can include the rest of the code that does this checking (namely the WPF binding on the datagrid, and a converter that calls the checking method with the property name as a string parameter) if needed.

Comment: @James -- In the OP: "I've removed the rest of the properties for brevity."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write an extension method like:

```
public static object GetPropValue(this object o, string propName)
{
    return o.GetType().GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.IgnoreCase)
            .GetValue(o);
}
```

and use it

```
if(localShipment.GetPropValue(value).Equals(originalShipment.GetPropValue(value)))
{
}
```

Comment: Ahh this is pretty much what i was looking for! I'll have to give this one a try.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the above code, "No overload for method 'GetValue' takes 1 arguments"

Comment: @user1412240 try `.GetValue(o,null);` You must be using an older version of .Net

Comment: Yeah sorry about that, i worked it out just after posting that comment, I'm stuck with .net 4.0 because i only have vs2010 licensed.

Answer (score 2):

You could define a common interface to your properties, then create a dictionary of properties like so:

```
var properties = new Dictionary<string, IProperty>();
```

and access them like this:

```
properties["CILRef"]
```

Comment: That is a pretty good idea, it would certainly help solve the secondary issue of having to continually add code if properties are added to this model. I'll have a play with this.

Answer (score 2):

I would say a `switch` statement is fine, however, you could do the body of the `case` in single lines using the [condition operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx)

```
switch (value)
{
    case "CILRef":
        return _localShipment.cilRef != _originalShipment.cilRef ? Colors.SkyBlue : Colors.White;
    case "ArrivedAtPortDate":
        return _localShipment.arrivatedAtPortDate != _originalShipment.arrivedAtPortDate ? Colors.SkyBlue : Colors.White;
    ...
}
```

But you would still have repetitive code here, you could take this a step further and have a `GetColor` method which took a function in

```
public Colors GetColor(Func<bool> condition)
{
    return condition() ? Colors.SkyBlue : Colors.White;
}
...
switch (value)
{
    case "CILRef":
        return GetColor(() => _localShipment.cilRef != _originalShipment.cilRef);
    case "ArrivedAtPortDate":
        return GetColor(() => _localShipment.arrivatedAtPortDate != _originalShipment.arrivedAtPortDate);
}
```

---

Looking at your code closer, it does appear you are comparing the same property on each shipping and you could literally reduce this to one check using Reflection

```
public Color HasChanged(string value)
{
    var date1 = _localShipment.GetType()
        .GetProperty(value)
        .GetValue(_localShipment, null);
    var date2 = _originalShipment.GetType()
        .GetProperty(value)
        .GetValue(_originalShipment, null);
    return date1 != date2 ? Colors.SkyBlue : Colors.White;
}
```

For brevity, you could create an extension method to wrap up the Reflection part

```
public static T Get<T>(this object obj, string name)
{
    return obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetValue(obj, null);
}
...
return _localShipment.Get<DateTime>(value) != _originalShipment.Get<DateTime>(value) ? Colors.SkyBlue : Colors.White;
```